# Saving value through subdocument with AngularJS and Mongoose(MEANJS)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I am trying to add a value to the 'UserID', 'UserName' keys these are the subdocument 'NetworkList' with: **this.NetworkList.UserID** in the controller. Using that breaks form submission, no errors in console.

When the form submits, it does add the value for **Id**.

**schema**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var NetworkSchema = new Schema({
   Id: {
    type: Number,
    default: '',
    trim: true
       },
NetworkList: {
    UserID: {
        type: Number,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    UserName: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
},
});
mongoose.model('Network', NetworkSchema);
```

**controller:**

```
angular.module('networks').controller('NetworksController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Networks',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Networks) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    // Create new Network
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Network object
        var network = new Networks ({
            Id: this.Id,
            UserID: this.NetworkList.UserID,
            UserName: this.NetworkList.UserName,

    network.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('networks/' + response._id);

            // Clear form fields
            $scope.Id = '';
            $scope.UserID = '';
            $scope.UserName = '';
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };

});
```

**form:**

```
<section data-ng-controller="NetworksController">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>New Network</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Id">ID</label>
                <label class="control-label" for="UserID">UserID</label>
                <label class="control-label" for="UserName">UserName</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="Id" id="Id" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" required>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="NetworkList.UserID" id="UserID" class="form-control" placeholder="UserID" required>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="NetworkList.UserName" id="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" required>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
            <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
                <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the network list be an array instead of an object in your schema? `NetworkList : [{UserId: ... }]`

Comment: yeah it can be, but i chose it to be an object :)